# How to extract SQL from SQL Server XML Deadlock Graphs

Tags: sql-server, powershell, xml-parsing

I have some SQL deadlocks I am trying to capture `mediaName` from. The deadlock report is in XML but the attribute i need is buried in XML, then SQL, then XML again. Here is an example.

XPATH for where the SQL starts is `/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf`, then the SQL is:

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 8; 
EXEC spM_Ext_InsertUpdateXML N'&lt;mediaRecords&gt;&lt;media 
title="This Is the title" mediaType="0" 
creationTime="2018-03-16T00:59:43" origSOM="01:00:00;00" notes="Air Date: 
2018-03-18 &amp;#xa;Air Window: 3 &amp;#xa;" mediaName="This is what i need" 
&gt;&lt;mediaInstances&gt;&lt;mediaInstance directory="here" 
duration="00:28:40;11" version="1" position="00:00:00;00" mediaSetId="34" 
creationStartTime="2018-03-16T00:59:43;25" creationEndTime="2018-03-
16T00:59:43;25"/&gt;&lt;/mediaInstances&gt;&lt;properties&gt;&lt; 
classifications&gt;&lt;classification category="HD" classification="Content 
Resolution"/&gt;&lt;/classifications&gt;&lt;markups&gt;&lt;markup 
name=""&gt;&lt;Item duration="00:00:10;00" orderNo="1" 
type="Dynamic" som="00:59:50;00" comment="" 
name="Segment"/&gt;&lt;/markup&gt;&lt;markup 
name="Segment"&gt;&lt;markupItem duration="00:08:41;10" orderNo="2" 
type="Dynamic" som="01:00:00;00" comment="Main Title and Segment 1 | 
ID:SEDC" name="Segment"/&gt;&lt;/markup&gt;&lt;markup 
name="Black"&gt;&lt;markup
```

See how the XML isnt using `<` and `>` for the elements but the `&lt` and `&gt` which adds complexity.

I am trying to extract only mediaName from this report but cant get past the above mentioned XPath with powershell. Was hoping someone might have an idea. I was using

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\Users\user\desktop\test.xml")

$xml.SelectNodes('/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf')  | select mediaName
```

I have also tried piping `select-xml` to `where-object` but I don't think I am using the right `$_.[input]`

With the help of tomalak and the answer below this is the fixed and working parsing script.

```
#report file location, edited by user when needed
$DeadlockReport =  "C:\Users\User\Desktop\xml_report1.xml"

# Create object to load the XML from the deadlock report and find the SQL within
$xml = New-Object xml 
$xml.Load($DeadlockReport) 
$inputbuf = $xml.SelectNodes('//deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf')
$value = $inputbuf.'#text' 

#find the internal XML and replace bad values, SQL, and truncation with RE
$value = $value -replace "^[\s\S]*?N'","" -replace "';\s*$","" -replace "<markup.*$","</properties></media></mediaRecords>" 

#append root elements to $value 
$fix = "<root>" + $value + "</root>"

#Load the XML after its been corrected
$payload.LoadXml($fix)

#find the nodes in the xml for mediaName
$mediaName = $payload.SelectNodes('//root/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName') 

#iterate through and return all media names. 
foreach($i in $mediaName)
    { 
return $mediaName 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is:

- an XML file,
- which contains a string value,
- which is SQL,
- which contains *another* string value,
- which is XML again.

So let's peel the onion.

First-off, please never load XML files like this

```
# this is bad code, don't use
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\Users\user\desktop\test.xml")
```

XML has sophisticated file encoding detection, and you are short-circuiting that by letting Powershell load the file. This can lead to data breaking silently because Powershell's `Get-Content` has no idea what actual encoding of the XML file is. (Sometimes the above works, sometimes it doesn't. "It works for me" doesn't mean that you're doing it right, it means that you're being lucky.)

This is the correct way:

```
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load("C:\Users\user\desktop\test.xml")
```

Here the [`XmlDocument` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) will take care of loading the file and transparently adapt to any encoding it might have. Nothing can break and you don't have to worry about file encodings.

Second, don't let the looks of the XML file in a text editor deceive you. As indicated, `/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf` contains a *string* as far as XML is concerned, the `<` and `>` and all the rest will be there when you look at the actual text value of the element.

```
$inputbuf = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf')
$value = $inputbuf.'#text'

Write-Host $value
```

Would print something like this, which is SQL:

```sql
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 8; 
EXEC spM_Ext_InsertUpdateXML N'<mediaRecords><media 
title="This Is the title" mediaType="0" 
creationTime="2018-03-16T00:59:43" origSOM="01:00:00;00" notes="Air Date: 
2018-03-18 &#xa;Air Window: 3 &#xa;" mediaName="This is what i need" 
><mediaInstances><mediaInstance directory="here" 
duration="00:28:40;11" version="1" position="00:00:00;00" mediaSetId="34" 
creationStartTime="2018-03-16T00:59:43;25" creationEndTime="2018-03-
16T00:59:43;25"/></mediaInstances><properties>< 
classifications><classification category="HD" classification="Content 
Resolution"/></classifications><markups><markup 
name=""><Item duration="00:00:10;00" orderNo="1" 
type="Dynamic" som="00:59:50;00" comment="" 
name="Segment"/></markup><markup 
name="Segment"><markupItem duration="00:08:41;10" orderNo="2" 
type="Dynamic" som="01:00:00;00" comment="Main Title and Segment 1 | 
ID:SEDC" name="Segment"/></markup><markup 
name="Black"><markup ...
</mediaRecords>';
```

And the XML you are interested in is actually a string inside this SQL. If the SQL follows this pattern...

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 8; 
EXEC spM_Ext_InsertUpdateXML N'<...>';
```

...we need to do three things in order to get to the XML payload:

1. Remove the enclosing SQL statements
2. Replace any `''` with `'` (because the `''` is the escaped quote in SQL strings)
3. Pray that part in-between does not contain any other SQL expressions

So

```
$value = $value -replace "^[\s\S]*?N'","" -replace "';\s*$","" -replace "''","'"
```

would remove everything up to and including `N'` and the `';` at the end, as well as replace all the duplicated single quotes (if any) with normal single quotes.

Adapt the regular expressions as needed. Replacing the SQL parts with regex isn't exactly clean, but if the expected input is very limited, like in this case, it'll do.

```
Write-Host $value
```

Now we should have a string that is *actually* XML. Let's parse it. This time, it's already in our memory, there isn't any file encoding to pay attention to. So it's actually all-right if we cast it to XML directly:

```
$payload = [xml]$value
```

And **now** we can query it for the value you are interested in:

```
$mediaName = $payload.SelectSingleNode("/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName")

Write-Host $mediaName
```

Comment: Duuuuudeeee! Thank you!!! I am barely learning scripting with Powershell and python so this is insanely helpful. I want to learn more and more scripting so bad but its so hard to find usefulness for it right now. That's really how I learn. Being shown something then having to do it multiple times. Thank you again!!  I will reply again if it doesn't work. Thank you also for the formatting help!

Comment: I am running into a few issues. 

First: I have an output error "_Cannot convert Value_" to which it prints the XML above. I believe the Extended Event logging is truncating the SQL query thus its cutting of the XML at the end. I used replace to add the missing XML elements. But that didnt solve my problem. 

Second: I now have a nice Script but `write-host $mediaName` is not  outputting anything. The XML errors now stopped and checking the xpath in what I believe to be the XML output works but that's it.

Comment: `$xml = New-Object xml 
$xml.Load("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.xml")

$inputbuf = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf')
$value = $inputbuf.'#text'

$value = $value -replace "^[\s\S]*?N'","" -replace "';\s*$","" -replace "''","'" -replace "<markup.*$","</properties></media></mediaRecords>"

$payload = [xml]$value

$mediaName = $payload.SelectSingleNode("/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName")

Write-Host $mediaName
`

Comment: General advice: You should put `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` at the top of your script. This way, Powershell stops at the first unhandled error, instead of running on with incomplete data. This is not a silver bullet, but it can help.

Comment: If the extended logging truncates the SQL statement, of course you can't convert it to XML. Maybe the truncation can be disabled somehow? I have no idea, but it's worth checking. Otherwise your make-shift solution of appending the missing parts manually is one (albeit ugly) way to do it.

Comment: If you have managed to get past `$payload = [xml]$value`, then `$payload = $payload.SelectSingleNode("/mediaRecords")` should give you a result. So should `$payload.SelectSingleNode("/mediaRecords/media")`. Debugging 101. Work your way up in complexity until it does not return anything anymore, that's where you need to pay attention.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you for the shove in the right direction!!!

`$DeadlockReport = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.xml"


$xml = New-Object xml 
$xml.Load($DeadlockReport) 
$inputbuf = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf') 
$value = $inputbuf.'#text'


$value = $value -replace "^[\s\S]*?N'","" -replace "';\s*$","" -replace "''","'" -replace "<markup.*$","</properties></media></mediaRecords>" 


$payload = [xml]$value 


$mediaName = $payload.SelectSingleNode("/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName")


return $mediaName `

Comment: Before it was getting stuck in $payload.

`PS C:\Windows\system32> $payload

mediaRecords
------------
mediaRecords`

I had some bad elements coming from one `-replace`. Once I changed that replace's XML string, `$payload` then became valid and everything worked.

Comment: Awesome! Unfortunately, next time it's not guaranteed that your XML payload is broken in the exact same way as here, so the solution to fix the XML is rather brittle. If you can find a way of increasing the maximum length of the `<inputbuf>` beyond the size of your typical XML file, this would be good.

Comment: Yes thats the next goal. I actually turned this into a module and have been using it as a parser for the deadlock report. The problem now is that I am only getting the 1st occurrence of mediaName where there are several more in the deadlock report. All at the same depth/xpath/node... Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the XPath `/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName` actually gives you all of them. It's `.SelectSingleNode()` that gives you only the first one. Use `.SelectNodes()` and PowerShell's `foreach` to get them all.

Comment: Every time i use `.SelectNodes()` i get `Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."` I have tracked it to `$payload = [xml]$value` When i remove `[xml]` it doesnt return any values but when i leave it I get that error.

Comment: `$DeadlockReport = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\xml_report1.xml"
$xml = New-Object xml 
$xml.Load($DeadlockReport) 

ForEach($inputbuf in $value){
$inputbuf = $xml.SelectNodes('/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf') 
$value = $inputbuf.'#text' 
}
$value = $value -replace "^[\s\S]*?N'","" -replace "';\s*$","" -replace "''","'" -replace "<markup.*$","</properties></media></mediaRecords>"

$payload = [xml]$value 

foreach($Name in $mediaName){

$mediaName = $payload.SelectSingleNode("/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName") 
}
return $mediaName`

Comment: I fixed it. I had to add root elements through another variable. Then i needed to not cast as XML but `.LoadXML() ` after concatenating the `<root></root>` elements onto the text from `$value`. Thank YOU for so much help with this. I do realize that i need more friends that know this kind of stuff.

Comment: @inFAM1S Thanks for the feedback, good to hear you've sorted it out eventually. Before I forget - as a final resort, if parsing the XML turns out to work not so well after all, you can use regex to find the value. I'm not a fan of using regex on XML at all, but after exhausting all other options, it's another way of doing it. `$mediaName = ([regex]'mediaName="([^"]*)"').Match($value).Groups[1].Value` gives me `This is what i need`. You'd have to make adjustments for supporting multiple matches, and the contents of `$mediaName` would still be XML-escaped, too.

Comment: thank you for the help! I will keep that in mind as this goes forward. Right now this is just to compare logs from SQL to our system and if it remains as is... It should continue to work (fingers crossed).

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I am too. Even if this doesnt get used in production it was a great way for me to learn! I finally got to see how each method is used and the changes it does to the text, how to load xml files and how the data gets set in the memory and what it looks like. So win win for me :)

Comment: Keep it up. There's a lot to learn, but I can see you're not bad at learning.

Comment: I do my best. Projects are what i need to learn. That and people i can poke and say "hey, what the eff" lol.

Comment: The people you can poke are here. I believe no well-put-together question has gone unanswered here, and I also think that asking better-than-average questions is easy. (Asking good questions in general is hard, but being better than the average at it isn't, if that makes sense.)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I try to give the best question possible but I sometimes don't know what I'm talking about so it makes it difficult. I did have a couple questions that went unanswered here.